# SwiftUI TextField foreground color issue

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make real time email validation, but the simulator has strange behaviour. When the email IS NOT valid, it should be red, when it IS valid, the color of the text should be black, but some characters stay red.

```
struct EmailText: View {
    
    @State var textFieldValue: String = ""
    
    private func isValid(_ s: String) -> Bool {
        // not real validation function, just for simplicity
        return Int.random(in: 0 ... 1) == 1
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $textFieldValue)
            .foregroundColor(isValid(textFieldValue) ? .black : .red)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Edit: I have updated the validation function from regex to simple condition, to exclude regex as a possible issue.

Comment: I guess your RegEx is wrong. Try /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: disable autocorrection.

```
TextField("", text: $textFieldValue)
            .foregroundColor(isValid(textFieldValue) ? .black : .red)
            .padding()
            .autocorrectionDisabled() // <----
```

Most certainly a SwiftUI bug that causes interference between the text highlighting of spell check warnings and the foreground color.

Comment: You are the best!!! :) It is working solution. I had suspicion that it behave strange when there is "typo" but wasn't sure, because the behaviour was "random".

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. Your RegEx is wrong. Use:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

To validate e-mail.

Comment: Swift is not accepting this regex format. I'm getting some "Invalid escape sequence in literal" in the regex. Also, I'm not sure if the issue is in regex, because for the same email address it sometimes works (whole text is black) and sometimes not. Also if you check the code, the text should be either red or black. Regular expression should not have effect on partial text coloring.

Comment: Normally a RegEx is defined by slashes... what seems to be added on my RegEx and your is not is the first and the last "/". Try without them.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tested code, Maybe It will help you

```
struct Demo1: View {
    @State private var email: String

      @State var emailIsValid: Bool = true

      

      public init(email: String = "")

      {

          self.email = email

      }
    var body: some View {
//        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        
        
        TextField("Email", text: $email)

            .onChange(of: email) { newValue in

                if(newValue.range(of:"^\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*$", options: .regularExpression) != nil) {

                    self.emailIsValid = true

                    print("valid")

                } else {

                    self.emailIsValid = false

                    print("invalid")

                }

            }

            .foregroundColor(emailIsValid ? Color.green : Color.red)

    }
}
```